# Bacula restore gives me information "... no files were found ...", what does it mean?

Tags: bacula

I have working Bacula setup and I'm testing various restore strategies to fulfill our documentation. Everything worked fine, but since couple days I"m receiving following message:

```
> The defined FileSet resources are:
>      1: FileSetJenkinsQuantum
>      2: dahmer-jenkins Select FileSet resource (1-2): 1
> +-------+-------+----------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------+ | JobId | Level | JobFiles | JobBytes     | StartTime           |
> VolumeName              |
> +-------+-------+----------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------+ | 2337  | F     | 9197084  | 108970727010 | 2015-07-05 02:05:03 |
> FullJenkinsQuantu-0110  | | 2367  | D     | 197686   | 5641957499   |
> 2015-07-12 02:05:04 | DiffJenkinsQuantum-0106 | | 2372  | I     |
> 110944   | 3984177676   | 2015-07-13 02:05:03 |
> IncrJenkinsQuantum-0078 |
> +-------+-------+----------+--------------+---------------------+-------------------------+ You have selected the following JobIds: 2337,2367,2372
> 
> Building directory tree for JobId(s) 2337,2367,2372 ...  Query failed:
> SELECT Path.Path, Filename.Name, T1.FileIndex, T1.JobId, LStat,
> DeltaSeq      FROM ( SELECT FileId, Job.JobId AS JobId, FileIndex,
> File.PathId AS PathId, File.FilenameId AS FilenameId, LStat     ,
> File.DeltaSeq AS DeltaSeq, Job.JobTDate AS JobTDate FROM Job, File, (
> SELECT MAX(JobTDate) AS JobTDate, PathId, FilenameId, DeltaSeq FROM (
> SELECT JobTDate, PathId, FilenameId, DeltaSeq FROM File JOIN Job USING
> (JobId) WHERE File.JobId IN (2337,2367,2372) UNION ALL SELECT
> JobTDate, PathId, FilenameId, DeltaSeq FROM BaseFiles JOIN File USING
> (FileId) JOIN Job  ON    (BaseJobId = Job.JobId) WHERE BaseFiles.JobId
> IN (2337,2367,2372) ) AS tmp GROUP BY PathId, FilenameId, DeltaSeq )
> AS T1 WHERE (Job.JobId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT BaseJobId FROM BaseFiles
> WHERE JobId IN (2337,2367,2372)) OR Job.JobId IN (2337,2367,2372)) AND
> T1.JobTDate = Job.JobTDate AND Job.JobId = File.JobId AND T1.PathId =
> File.PathId AND T1.FilenameId = File.FilenameId ) AS T1 JOIN Filename
> ON (Filename.FilenameId = T1.FilenameId) JOIN Path ON (Path.PathId =
> T1.PathId) WHERE FileIndex > 0 ORDER BY T1.JobTDate, FileIndex ASC:
> ERR=disk I/O error
> 
> 
> For one or more of the JobIds selected, no files were found, so file
> selection is not possible. Most likely your retention policy pruned
> the files.
> 
> Do you want to restore all the files? (yes|no): yes Bootstrap records
> written to /var/spool/bacula/unagi-dir.restore.1.bsr
> 
> The job will require the following    Volume(s)                
> Storage(s)                SD Device(s)
> ===========================================================================
>    
>     FullJenkinsQuantu-0110    unagi-sd                  JenkinsQuantumStorage    
>     DiffJenkinsQuantum-0106   unagi-sd                  JenkinsQuantumStorage    
>     IncrJenkinsQuantum-0078   unagi-sd                  JenkinsQuantumStorage    
> 
> Volumes marked with "*" are online.
> 
> 
> 9,505,714 files selected to be restored.
```

What does this message and situation mean? It seems that all required files are available but I'm concerned that maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this critical detail:

> ```
> ERR=disk I/O error
> ```

Fix your hardware issues and you should not have this problem again.